# Angular extending class throwing can't resolve parameters error

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and facing below issue while extending dashboard class with base class.

Please help whats wrong I am doing. I tried finding similar queries but was not able to find it.

PFA Code and Error image file.

```js
// Base Component

export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUrl: string;
  constructor(private route: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUrl = this.route.url;
    console.log(this.currentUrl);
  }

}


// main component

export class DashboardComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(e) { 
    super(e);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.currentUrl);
  }

}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQ1P.jpg)

Comment: kindly post the code for DashboardComponent also

Comment: main component is the dashboard component. I just replaced the name for easy understanding

Comment: Please add your imports to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The DashboardComponent are supposed to pass all parameters that BaseComponent needs. So you need to inject these parameters in the DashboardComponent.

```
export class DashboardComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(route: Router) { 
    super(route);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.currentUrl);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. what if i have more than one dependency. Do i need to pass allof them to super();

Comment: Yes, you need to pass them all to super. =/